# send applescript a url ,if the url file's extension is ".mov" download it to desktop

Tags: macos, applescript

I'd like to remote control my mac mini(using as a NAS with Mac OS X 10.8.2 Server)download files from URL.
I think applescript can realize it.

So I'm puzzled by two problems:
1.How can I send URLs to the Applescript(I can only think of HTTP POST);
2.How the applescript receive the URLs then identify file's extension,if matching "mov" download it to desktop?

someone have good idea? If you can detailed told me that is the best.

Comment: I have made a web server on the mac mini can run a web page on it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at man curl, which should be able to do everything you need.

```
set xxx to do shell script "curl http://superuser.com/"
```